# Inject Index of Current item when binding to a repeater

Tags: .net, data-binding, binding, repeater

I am binding a `List<HtmlImage>` to a repeater

Its actually a nested repeater and the list is one of the properties that the parent repeater is binding to

I want to spit out the index of the current dataitem into the id property of the `<li>`

I've put a comment where I want the index to appear below

I have the following:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="ImageListRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Images") %>'>
                            <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate> 
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li id='<% **I want the Index Here**  %>'><%# RenderImage(Container.DataItem)%></li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

What are the options?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `<%# Container.ItemIndex %>` ?

Comment: thank you...I knew it was something like that. I had tried Databinder, the id of the repeater, Datasource, but intellisense was showing that none of those had an index property