# is there any way to get the index of an Item from a DataTable inside of a Repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the index of the DataItem from the DataTable and insert that into the repeater. I tried this solution: [Inject Index of Current item when binding to a repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722486/inject-index-of-current-item-when-binding-to-a-repeater)

but that does not give me what I want. that solution only gives me the location of the item within the Repeater, but I want the location of the item within its source DataTable.

The reason for this is because I want to number my search results, and if I use the above solution then the numbers reset on pagination.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int resultIndex = (myRepeater.CurrentPageIndex * myRepeater.PageSize) + ItemIndex + 1`